# Hibernate: Update an object -> also unwanted delete statements are performed

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate as an ORM in my Java application.
I have a Project <-> Person manytomany-relation and the Project is the mapping owner.

Now I have the problem, that I want to update the Project. The Project has an id, a name, ... and a Set of Persons. Doing an update, the persons are all deleted in the Project_Person join table, the SQL statements on the console:

```
Hibernate: update Project set description=?, name=? where id=?
Hibernate: delete from Project_Person where project_id=?
```

But I do not want that the delete-statement is executed.

I have this in my Java application:

```
this.projService.updateProject(p);
```

where p is the Project, but in a POJO way without the Set of Persons. So I thought, to make it "Hibernate-ready" I make this within a separate transaction a findProjectById, so I fetch the project from the database:

```
Project proj = this.projService.findProjectById(p.getId());
proj.setName(p.getName());
proj.setDescription(p.getDescription());
```

So I get the Hibernate-ready Project object, change the values and then tell him to update the project. But the Set is in the debugger view a PersistentSet and there are no Persons in it (I think, because they are lazy-loaded).
But updating with a

```
session.update(p);
```

within a new transaction, I get the update statement, and the unwanted delete statement.
How can I avoid the delete statement?

Do I have to create a special SQL statement so that only the database table fields which I want to update will be updated? Or are there other/better solutions?

Best Regards.

---

**Update**
This throws a LazyInitializationException:

```
public Project findProjectById(int projectId) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
    try {
        Project project = (Project)sess.createQuery("from Project where id = "+projectId).list().get(0);
        tx.commit();
        System.out.println(project.getPersons().size());
        return project;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot of the Debugger**:

http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/2020/screendebugger.png

**HibernateUtil**

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    // SessionFactory of Hibernate
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed. " + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot before the tx.commit()**

http://img808.imageshack.us/img808/9624/screendebugger2.png

Comment: very odd. try printing the size before committing the transaction.

Comment: I put a screenshot of the debugger right before the tx.commit() line. Update: Putting here before the line tx.commit() the getPersons().size(), I get it!

Comment: So, the Session is closed after committing. So what can I do to solve this problem with the unwanted SQL delete statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means (as you suggested) that your collection is empty. But it's not due to lazy-loading - the debugger would allow you to load the collection. Perhaps it is empty for another reason. Confirm this by showing `collection.size()`.

The other part of the issue is the cascade. If you have defined to cascade `delete-orphan`, then either remove it, or make sure the collection is actually filled.

Comment: I did not define a cascade like delete-orphan. I take a deeper look into the Set<Person>persons of the project: there is no Person. A size() of the collection will always return a LazyInitialization error.

Comment: I put an example, which throws a LazyInit exception in my question.

Comment: Then place your breakpoint in a method where the session is still not closed.

Comment: I am not quite sure, if I understand you correctly, but I put a link to a screenshot to my question, so you can see the debugger view, and the source code with break point.

Comment: @Tim - put the breakpoint in the `projectService`, right before returning the object. The session is available there (and is closed in the controller, perhaps you have a transaction manager around your service layer)

Comment: From the code you see in my question "findProjectById(int projectId)" that is the ProjectDao implementation. The projectService (its implementation) only calls the Interface of the Dao and returns the project object, so what you see in the screenshot is the same. The project in my controller has the same values like the project returned from the DaoImpl and the ServiceImpl. I checked it twice, the project object has the same values like you see in the screenshot.

Comment: The DaoImpl and the ServiceImpl must have an active hibernate session, and hence not throw the lazy exception.

Comment: I updated the question. I have a HibernateUtil.java which is used in my DaoImpl, but the session seems to be opened and not to be closed?!

Comment: I get my error! Aaaargh: I wrote: this.projService.updateProject(p);
 but it must be the Project which I fetch from the database: this.projService.updateProject(proj); Thank you very much, with your size() and a lot of testing, I get the error. Now it works without other modfications.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the call "update".

The following code:

```
Project proj = this.projService.findProjectById(p.getId());
proj.setName(p.getName());
proj.setDescription(p.getDescription());
```

Does not then need the update as the proj reference is persistent and any changes to it will be saved. This is a feature of hibernate and other ORM's known as transparent persistence.

see [here](http://analysis102.blogspot.com/2008/12/hibernate-what-does-update-actually.html) for more information on hibernates update method.

Comment: Yes, but my model closes the transaction, so I need tzo call it in my case. Your link is okay, but I do not use it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you update the Project object in a new transaction you probably should associate the object with the new Session using

```
session.merge(project)
```

Maybe that detects the uninitialized PersistentSet, replaces it with a new one from the new Session and will make sure the entries of the Set are not deleted. Otherwise Hibernate maybe not be able to handle the Set since the transaction that created it is already closed and assumes that it is empty.